# Restart tornado webserver when idle

Tags: python, tornado

I was working with the Tornado webserver and wanted to understand on how to determine if the server has been idle for a while and then restart it.

I was trying to determine the time difference between self.requests to determine if no request has been received for a while. But is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use a global variable to hold the timestamp of the last request and update it whenever you process requests. Something like:

```
#startup initialization code
_last_request = datetime.datetime.now()

#we will use these variables later
interval = datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
idle_timeout = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1800)

...

#update timestamp in handler(s)
global _last_request 
_last_request = datetime.datetime.now()
```

You will then add a function which checks from time to time the _last_request variable:

```
def idle_check():
    if _last_request - datetime.datetime.now() > idle_timeout: 
        #stop the IOLoop
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
    else:
        #schedule to run again
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(interval, idle_check)
```

Do  not forget to call the idle_check function before starting the IOLoop.

Comment: Since I don't think there is any other way for this to be done. I will accept this answer.